# How to redirect "You must be logged in to post a comment." link to another link on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a word press website and would prefer to redirect this default login link to another link instead as I have done up a pop-up sign in instead.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this to your functions.php file and modify it with your link

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', function( $fields ) {
    $fields['must_log_in'] = sprintf( 
        __( '<p class="must-log-in">
                 You must <a href="%s">Register</a> or 
                 <a href="%s">Login</a> to post a comment.</p>' 
        ),
        wp_registration_url(),
        wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) )   
    );
    return $fields;
});
```

Comment: glad to hear that @RajdeepSinghHundal   :-)

Comment: There is another default link for the comments section "Login in to reply". I tried to do the same method as the above and changed the class to "comment-reply-login" as I saw this was the class when I inspected the page. However it does not seem to work. Any ideas ? Thanks :)

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal It depends on hook actually, But not on class

Comment: Ah i see, any ideas how to solve it ? I just want it to be the same as the previous one which worked.

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal. Can you tell me where the link actually is? In above screenshot I can see only one default Comment section link

Comment: I've added the picture above

Comment: OK nvm, I've managed to do it haha :)) Thanks for the help, I changed the comment-template.php in the wp-includes folder. I located the class and modified esc_url()  with the link needed.

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal. Don't modify anything inside wp-includes folder. Its really a bad practice to do so. Core files are never be touched. Wordpress provide hooks to overwrite

Comment: I see, sorry haha am quite new to this, could you provide a hook to solve my problem above and explain how it is created ? Thanks !

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal. You can add this code to modify link
`if ( ! function_exists( 't5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in' ) )
{
    add_filter( 'comment_reply_link', 't5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in' );

    /**
     * Replaces the log-in link with an empty string.
     *
     * @param  string $link
     * @return string
     */
    function t5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in( $link )
    {
        if ( empty ( $GLOBALS['user_ID'] ) && get_option( 'comment_registration' ) )
        {
            return ''; // add your link here
        }

        return $link;
    }
}`

Comment: Yep, just tried this, it works, thanks for the help man, really appreciate it

Comment: can you create a new question for this, if you appreciate  and provide me the link :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find comments.php file in your theme's folder. There you need to find this message and change link's href.

Comment: I cant seem to find the message in comments.php

Answer (score 0):

If its a popup workflow then you need to hijack the click into the link in your Javascript and show the popup.

You do not provide a lot of information about yoru specific scenario so pelase let me provide some basic example below

```
$(function() {
  $('.must-log-in a'),on('click', function(){
    e.preventDefault();

    //call the function to show the pop up here
  });
});
```

Comment: Where would i find the the above mentioned function (the must-log-in one)? I'm using the memberfull plugin to create a paywall site, and thus it changes the log in's to a pop-up view. This means that I would have to find the memberfull function which calls the popup and insert it in the function mentioned above right ?

Comment: And do you have a specific link to this membership plugin page? If yes then in the code above you can put something like `window.location.href = 'https://your-page.com/link`;` which will redirect user on click